# Dropdown box getting values from mySQL shows blanbk entries

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm using the template from this mySQL x AJAX tutorial (http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html) to create dependent dropdowns.

### **How the code should work:**

Coach selects what activity group ($activity) he wants to browse from box one.
Box two the populates with a list of players($username) who are part of that activity.

It does the above, but the entries show up blank as opposed to printing the name - see screenshot attached. Below is the piece

```js
<?php
if($_POST['activity'])
{
$activity=$_POST['activity'];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id AND username FROM player WHERE activity='$activity'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id=$row['id'];
$username=$row['username'];
$activity=$row['activity'];
echo '<option value="'.$username.'">'.$username.'</option>';

}
}

?>
```

I've messed around with the number of entries in the db, and the blank values change respectively (when changed to 5 people being in group, 5 blank spaces show, etc.)

It's really odd because of the fact it appears to be working, just not showing the names.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fixing your query. You are ANDing the values id and username

```
SELECT id, username FROM player WHERE activity='$activity'
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `isset` your `$_POST['activity']`.